# How to make wizard in php?

Tags: php, css, wizard

[image]

**How to make wizard in php?**

I want to make a wizard menu same the example. but I don't know begin to do?
Is it jQuery ul-tabs?

Help me please.

Comment: You can use Agile UI, it has a "Wizard" component: http://agile-ui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making it in PHP will be not very user friendly, since on every step it will refresh the page and you have to keep track of all form fields and state in `$_SESSION`, there are many jquery plug in to make wizard forms.

**jQuery form wizard**

1. http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples
2. http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-step-form-wizard/

Using jQuery will make your life easier, just go step by step and at end save the form to server.